# Selecting records from a particular letter onwards

Tags: sql, sql-server

Taking in consideration a table `tbl_users`, I want to get a list of all users start from a certain letter and all the subsequent letters. For example, if I choose the letter 'C' it will display all users starting with 'C' and all the successive letters (i.e. 'D', 'E', etc.). How is it done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use this WHERE clause:

```
WHER username >= 'C'
```

Answer (score 1):

Have this as the condition.

```
SUBSTRING(UPPER(name),1,1) >= 'C'
```

Haven't tried it. If it doesn't work, please provide your table structure

Answer (score 1):

I did not test this, but I would think something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_users
WHERE SUBSTRING(tbl_users.UserName, 0, 1) >= 'C'
```